# Expanding text with button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a div of particular height showing some text. I am trying to expand it using jquery.
This is my button code

```
 <button class="btn btn-blog pull-right marginBottom10" id="expand">More Information</button>
```

This is the text i am trying to expand

```
 <p id="sc">
  {{x.content}}
 </p>
```

This is my css for p

```
#sc{
height: 7.5em;
padding: 2px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

And this is my script

```
  <script> $(document).ready(function(){document.getElementById("expand").onclick = function() { document.getElementById("sc").style.height = 'auto';}});</script>
```

I am using angularJS.
But the height auto property is not working on div.Nothing happens when i click the button
Please help

Comment: Any error in browser console when you click on button? did you added jQuery library before script code. Why mixing jQuery with javascript,do like this:-`<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#expand").on('click',function() { 
  $("#sc").css({'height':'auto'});
 });
});
</script>`

Comment: can't understand why you are using jQuery for simple things when you are already using angularjs which can give you the solution for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only proper way to do this would be to do it in AngularJS, and even though they work - all answers are here doing jQuery way inside AngularJS which is not a way to go. If you want jQuery answer for this - remove AngularJS tag from it and you will get jQuery answer - even though other answers covered this.

First thing - don't use id's for styles it will be difficult to override that later - so set up class. If you like that id you can keep it but make your styles in class like this:

HTML:

```
<p id="sc" class="sc">
  {{x.content}}
</p>
```

CSS - I added `auto-height` class for later:

```
.sc {
  height: 7.5em;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sc.auto-height {
  height: auto;
}
```

So AngularJS has `ng-style` and `ng-class` which you can use to set styles based on parameters to do this you could set on your element like this:

```
<p id="sc" class="sc" ng-class="{'auto-height':autoHeight}">
  {{x.content}}
</p>
```

Now considering this is all in AngularJS as you said (you have some kind of controller wrapped around this code) all you need to do is this:

```
<button class="btn btn-blog pull-right marginBottom10" id="expand" ng-click="autoHeight=!autoHeight">More Information</button>
```

To explain how this works:

- you have 2 classes in css: `.sc` which is your class (before it was
  id) and new `.auto-height` class which combined with .sc will
  override height css property.
- you have `autoHeight` property on $scope - it's not defined anywhere
  in the app so at beginning of app lifecycle it's `undefined`
- ng-class="{'auto-height': autoHeight}" will set up auto-height class
  on element as long as `autoHeight` on $scope is true - as I said
  before at beginning it's undefined which is falsy - so class won't be
  set.
- in the end ng-click on button with change autoHeight not to be autoHeight,        so if it's falsy it will become truthy - on next click it will become falsy - so basically you toggle it.

All of this is not tested but I'm confident that as long as you have AngularJS in your app it will work. If you don't have it you can check it in previous answers they have it there. You could also use `ng-style` here so feel free to check documentation below.

Documentation for `ng-class`:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Documentation for `ng-style`:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

**UPDATE:**

This is fiddle showing you correct way to do it - if you have only one button and multiple ng-repeats:
https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/j9eqvpzr/1/

And I see in your previous comments you have ng-repeat so I made a fiddle showing way of doing it with ng-repeat and multiple buttons, main thing here you will need to set up show/hide property on specific array element (with $index), I gave a guess to your model name and how it looks like but it's definitely similar, you could add showHide properties on your repeated array that would be best way but if you can't modify inside fiddle you have a map function that just creates array of false values - same amount as in repeated array.

One thing you should keep in mind if you have that ng-repeat you can't set id on element - id's should be unique per element per page - so only one id with same name can exist on page, so I removed id's. If you need id's set it up with this:

```
id="sc{{$index}}"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/j9eqvpzr/3/

Comment: Most elegant way of doing it..Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 3):

***In angularJs itself you can do it like below (No jQuery needed):-***

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#sc')).css('height', 'auto');
    };
  }]);
```

```css
#sc{
  height: 7.5em;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button class="btn btn-blog pull-right marginBottom10" id="expand" ng-click="myFunc()">More Information</button>
    <p id="sc">
    What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

***But if you want to do in jQuery then:-***

1.Make sure you added jQuery library before script code.

2.Don't mix jQuery syntax with javascript syntax.

Do like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#expand").on('click',function() { 
    $("#sc").css({'height':'auto'});
  });
});
```

```css
#sc{
height: 7.5em;
padding: 2px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-blog pull-right marginBottom10" id="expand">More Information</button>

 <p id="sc">
 What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </p>
```

***Note:-*** content need to be that much so it exceeds from  the hight you mentioned otherwise all text will shown initially and button click will do nothing.

Comment: I tried doing it with angular as you suggested. 
Thanks for suggesting the angular way of doing it.I am new to angular.This works perfectly,but in my page i have multiple p tags each with id sc which iam loading using ng-repeat.This works for the first button.when i click the button of second p tag,it doesn't work.can you suggest why is it happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: @Shehzadikhushi  if all button and paragraph are sharing same id then code will not work.`id` need to be unique per element

Comment: Well if you check my solution it should have everything you need in AngularJS way.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with this one too, a simplified one

```js
function clickhere() { 
 document.getElementById("sc").style.height = 'auto';
}
```

```html
<p id="sc">
   {{x.content}}
</p>
<button class="btn btn-blog pull-right marginBottom10" id="expand" onclick="clickhere();">More Information</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.x = [{
      'content':'Test',
              },
             {
      'content':'Test1',
              },
              {
      'content':'Test2',
             }];
  $scope.buttonClick = function(id){
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#sc'+id)).css('height','auto');
  }
}
```

```css
.sc{
height: 7.5em;
padding: 2px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="y in x">
      <p id="sc{{$index}}" class='sc'>
        {{y.content}}
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-blog pull-right marginBottom10" id="expand" ng-click="buttonClick($index);">More Information</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest to use angularjs and remove jQuery if you are using jQuery for such things which can be done in angularjs. You can try the below code which is purely in angularjs and does the same thing in simple steps. I haven't used jQuery at all. Hope it helps you.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.x = {
    'content': 'Test'
  };
  $scope.buttonClick = function() {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#sc')).css('height', 'auto')
  }
}
```

```css
#sc {
  height: 7.5em;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <p id="sc">
      {{x.content}}
    </p>
    <button class="btn btn-blog pull-right marginBottom10" id="expand" ng-click="buttonClick()">More Information</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the angular way of doing it.I am new to angular.This works perfectly,but in my page i have multiple p tags each with id sc which iam loading using ng-repeat.This works for the first button.when i click the button of second p tag,it doesn't work.can you suggest why is it happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: you can only have 1 id with same value on a page.

Comment: As i am using ng-repeat,i dont think there is another way of adding different id to the button.Can you suggest some alternative for this?

Comment: There is a way. i will edit the answer according to ng-repeat example

Comment: i have added another snippet which is based on ng-repeat as you want. Initially i am setting the heigth using `.sc` class. Also i have created dynamic id's using `$index` of ng-repeat which gives the index and passing the insex to the function. Just check it out